# AWS Glue S3 to Redshift, break json to multiple rows

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have JSON files in S3 in below format.

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "itemList": [{
      itemUsers: {
           user_1: "user1",
           user_2: "user2"
      },
      userType: "admin"
    },{
      itemUsers: {
           user_1: "user1",
           user_2: "user3",
           user_3: "user4"
      },
      userType: "customer"
    }
  ]
}
```

In above json, itemUsers can have any number of keys. We want to have separate row for each key.

I'm running Glue crawler job and need help in editing Glue crawler sparks code to achieve this.

Output should be in the below format.

```
id   |  Users | userType
-------------------------
1234 |  user1 | admin
1234 |  user2 | admin
1234 |  user1 | customer
1234 |  user3 | customer
1234 |  user4 | customer
```

Comment: You may want to look at this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/

Comment: @mailtobash I did check this before but it works if number of keys are same. But in my case, number of keys can change. Also, that example tells how to create separate column out of each field, not on how to make multiple rows